# How to SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT) and WHERE conditional on Ms.Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I just wanted to simply count using where conditional and yet this query ask me for parameter instead of automatically execute the query

```
SELECT COUNT(ActDiscDischargingPort) from(
SELECT DISTINCT ActDiscDischargingPort FROM SelisihLoadVSActualLoadTable) WHERE SchLoadVessel LIKE "XB24 - MV. MEMPHIS" AND SchLoadVoyageNo LIKE "0019";
```

What is the proper way of writing this query?

Found the answer, turn out the query has to be like this

```
SELECT COUNT(ActDiscDischargingPort) from ( SELECT DISTINCT ActDiscDischargingPort FROM SelisihLoadVSActualLoadTable WHERE SchLoadVoyageNo LIKE "XB24 - MV. MEMPHIS" AND SchLoadVessel LIKE "0019" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Every derived table must have its own alias. 
The correct syntax would be

```
SELECT
  COUNT(ActDiscDischargingPort)
from(
    SELECT
      DISTINCT ActDiscDischargingPort
    FROM
      SelisihLoadVSActualLoadTable
  ) AS T
WHERE
  SchLoadVessel LIKE "XB24 - MV. MEMPHIS"
  AND SchLoadVoyageNo LIKE "0019";
```

You can further speed up your query by optimizing it a bit.

Comment: unfortunately this query still ask me for parameter, while the column itself actually exist on the table

Comment: Show the log that you get.

Comment: nvm, found it. i posted the answer in original post